# jQuery jScrollPane Synchronize Scroll

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

Is it possible to synchronize two scrolls?

Answer (score 2):

Add this function to your code:

```
  jQuery.fn.synchronizeScroll = function() {
             var elements = this;
             if (elements.length <= 1) return;

             elements.scroll(
             function() {
                 var left = $(this).scrollLeft();
                 var top = $(this).scrollTop();
                 elements.each(
                 function() {
                     if ($(this).scrollLeft() != left) $(this).scrollLeft(left);
                     if ($(this).scrollTop() != top) $(this).scrollTop(top);
                 }
                 );
             });
          }
```

Then, you can just synchronize all the scrollbars within an element like so:

```
$(“jqueryselectorgoeshere”).synchronizeScroll();
```

Comment: Looks like a nice solution but I'm not sure it will work with jScrollPane... jScrollPane doesn't effect the scrollLeft and scrollTop properties of the scrolled element...

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty easy to do so by binding to the `jsp-scroll-y` [event](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html) and then calling the [`scrollToY` API method](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html#scrollToY).

Or, since jScrollPane also dispatches plain `scroll` events you could adapt Peter Of The Corn's solution by using [`getContentPositionY`](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html#getContentPositionY) instead of `scrollTop()` and `scrollToY` instead of `scrollTop(value)` (and likewise for the left/ top properties)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* This is my solution. thank both*/

$c1= $("#c1").jScrollPane();
$c2= $("#c2").jScrollPane();
$("#c1").bind(
        'jsp-scroll-y',
        function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom)
        {
            if($(this).find(".jspDrag").hasClass("jspActive")){
            $c2.data('jsp').scrollToY(scrollPositionY)
            console.log('Handle jsp-scroll-y', this,
                        'scrollPositionY=', scrollPositionY,
                        'isAtTop=', isAtTop,
                        'isAtBottom=', isAtBottom);
            }
        }
    )
$("#c2").bind(
        'jsp-scroll-y',
        function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom)
        {
            if($(this).find(".jspDrag").hasClass("jspActive")){
            $c1.data('jsp').scrollToY(scrollPositionY)
            console.log('Handle jsp-scroll-y', this,
                        'scrollPositionY=', scrollPositionY,
                        'isAtTop=', isAtTop,
                        'isAtBottom=', isAtBottom);
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that will make a sticky column, and a sticky row. Set overflow: hidden on #rowHeader, #columnHeader

```
            $("#dataTable").bind('jsp-scroll-y', function(event, scrollPositionY) {
                $("#rowHeader").scrollTop(scrollPositionY);
            }).bind('jsp-scroll-x',function(event, scrollPositionX) {
                $("#columnHeader").scrollLeft(scrollPositionX);
            }).jScrollPane();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of velozyrapthor is correct and working.
The only thing I added to my code is the 'click on the track' event.
When you click on the track it jumps to position.

Because my solution was involving a horizontal scroll bar, I changed the events to the horizontal ones.

this is my code:

```
$c1=$('#c1').jScrollPane();
$c2=$('#c2').jScrollPane();
//sync the two boxes to scroll together
//bind the scroll to c1
$("#c1").bind(
                 'jsp-scroll-x',
                 function(event, scrollPositionX, isAtTop, isAtBottom)
                 {
                     if($(this).find(".jspDrag").hasClass("jspActive"))
                     {
                         $c2.data('jsp').scrollToX(scrollPositionX)
                     }
                 }
             );
//bind the jump when clicking on the track
$("#c1").bind('mousedown',function()
{
    $c2.data('jsp').scrollToX($c1.data('jsp').getContentPositionX());
});
//bind the scroll to c2
$("#c2").bind(
                 'jsp-scroll-x',
                 function(event, scrollPositionX, isAtTop, isAtBottom)
                 {
                     if($(this).find(".jspDrag").hasClass("jspActive"))
                     {
                         $c1.data('jsp').scrollToX(scrollPositionX)
                     }
                 }
             );
//bind the jump when clicking on the track
$("#c2").bind('mousedown',function()
{
    $c1.data('jsp').scrollToX($c2.data('jsp').getContentPositionX());
});
```