# jscrollpane - synchronize two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-jscrollpane

I have a scrollbar customized with jscrollpane.js. How can I make this scrollbar control scrolling of another div? The second div has overflow: hidden.

I know this should be possible; there's a few suggestions at this link, but for some reason none of them works for me..
[jQuery jScrollPane Synchronize Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147596/jquery-jscrollpane-syncronize-scroll)

Can this be done, and how / where to attach working code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out: Made both divs scroll with one customized scrollbar by using jscrollpane and this code in head:

```
$(function()
{
$("#div2").bind('jsp-scroll-y', function(event, scrollPositionY) {
$("#div1").scrollTop(scrollPositionY);
}).jScrollPane();
$("#document").jScrollPane();
});
```